# How can I fix white characters on menus and the Launcher not disappearing?

Tags: updates

On 12.04 LTS, I was trying to install some packages for dependencies of the allegro game development library. One of the packages was `libwxgtk2.8-0`. After installing, a red cross appeared near my user name and clock. Then the computer froze, so I removed the battery.

When I restarted my computer, it started booting but got stuck at a black screen with the line "Checking battery state"

I solved that problem by running:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome-power-manager
```

However, now the Launcher fails to ever disappear. Moreover, the characters in most applications have turned white:

[image]

What could be the problem, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by "windows bar"?
also you asked two different questions. your gedit characters being white is probably not related. check your [gedit preferences](http://i.imgur.com/oOBaB.png).

Comment: thanks, i will try. windows bar is running applications' little buttons bar

Comment: @duxk.gh i edited my question

Comment: ok a few things: 1. for future reference, the menu on the left is called the launcher. 2. what version of ubuntu are you using? 3. what was the original problem that made you re-install power manager, and is that fixed now? i quickly searched and most "checking battery state" problems are boot related and are solved by re-installing the graphics drivers. where did you find the answer you followed?

Comment: @duxk.gh thanks very much. i edited my question

Comment: alright @tuxi i posted an answer. i'm really not sure if it will work but it's worth a try.
by the way, the next time your computer freezes just turn it off by pressing the power button for a while instead of taking out the battery.

Answer (score 0):

This might just be a matter of changed appearance settings. Go to System Settings > Appearance. Then try to change around two things.

To hopefully fix the white characters, toggle with the themes in "Look":

[image]

Then to fix the launcher from failing to disappear, switch to the "Behavior" tab and toggle with / set auto-hide the launcher to "On", like it is in the image below:

[image]